# Remove duplicate lines while keeping the bottom lines

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates

I would like to remove duplicate lines in R keeping the information of the lower lines, that is, from this data:

```
example <- structure(list(var1 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6), var2 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), var3 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), 
    var4 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), var5 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 
    0, 1, 1, 0, 0), Year = 2001:2009), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to remove the duplicates keeping the lines at the bottom, so that I get:

```
example1 <- structure(list(var1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), var2 = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), var3 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), var4 = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
0), var5 = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), Year = c(2002, 2004, 2005, 2006, 
2007, 2009)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Is it possible to apply the `duplicated` function or the `distinct` function of the `dplyr package?

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
example %>%
  group_by(var1) %>%
  slice_tail()
```

- output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 6
# Groups:   var1 [6]
   var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  Year
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1     1     0     0     1     1  2002
2     2     0     0     1     0  2004
3     3     0     0     0     0  2005
4     4     0     1     1     1  2006
5     5     0     0     1     1  2007
6     6     0     0     0     0  2009
```

Answer (score 2):

The @ThomasIsCoding response, with the dplyr tools, worked well. I found another possibility, which seems faster:

```
example1 <- example[!duplicated(example$var1, fromLast = T), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

`distinct` keeps 1st row in each group, if you want to keep last row you can reverse the rows and then apply `distinct`.

```
library(dplyr)

example %>%
  slice(n():1) %>%
  distinct(var1, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  arrange(var1)

#  var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 Year
#1    1    0    0    1    1 2002
#2    2    0    0    1    0 2004
#3    3    0    0    0    0 2005
#4    4    0    1    1    1 2006
#5    5    0    0    1    1 2007
#6    6    0    0    0    0 2009
```

Alternatively you can also use `slice` :

```
example %>% group_by(var1) %>% slice(n())
```